# Clojure Korma: Cannot run an aggregate count

Tags: macros, clojure, korma

I'm trying to run a simple query using Clojure+Korma to extract the number of records.
This is what I'm trying to do:

```
(defmacro number-of [ref & filter]
  `(let [basetmp# (-> (kc/select* ~ref)
                      (kc/aggregate (count :*) :cnt))]
     (if ~filter
       (-> basetmp#
           (kc/where ~filter))
       basetmp#)))
```

However if I try to use this macro I get an error message saying:
 Wrong number of args (2) passed to: **core$count**

The query would perfectly work if executed in a function but there's something wrong/missing 
in the macro I cannot spot :(

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: I think your `count` is `clojure.core/count` instead of Korma's count function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by ponzao you are picking up the wrong count.

Looking at the macroexpansion

```
(number-of 'foo)  ;; expands to....

(clojure.core/let [basetmp__9167__auto__ (clojure.core/->
                                          (korma.core/select* 'foo)
                                          (korma.core/aggregate
                                            (clojure.core/count :*)
                                            :cnt))]
  (if nil
    (clojure.core/-> basetmp__9167__auto__ (korma.core/where nil))
    basetmp__9167__auto__))
```

So you need to prevent the count in your macro being expanded as `clojure.core/count`, you can do this with a unquote/quote thus:

```
(defmacro number-of [ref & filter]
  `(let [basetmp# (-> (kc/select* ~ref)
                      (kc/aggregate (~'count :*) :cnt))]
     (if ~filter
       (-> basetmp#
           (kc/where ~filter))
       basetmp#)))
```

Which then expands as expected...

```
(clojure.core/let [basetmp__9137__auto__ (clojure.core/->
                                          (korma.core/select* 'foo)
                                          (korma.core/aggregate
                                            (count :*)
                                            :cnt))]
  (if nil
    (clojure.core/-> basetmp__9137__auto__ (korma.core/where nil))
    basetmp__9137__auto__))
```

The resultant SQL looks reasonable:

```
(kc/as-sql (number-of 'foo))
"SELECT COUNT(*) \"cnt\" FROM \"foo\""
```

**UPDATE:**
From the comments "What does the count actually represent?" - If you realize that `kc/aggregate` is also a macro and that the arguments are a 'SQL aggregate' DSL of sorts, then you can expand the `kc/aggregate` call too. You find there's a function, `parse-aggregate` in  [engine.clj](https://github.com/korma/Korma/blob/master/src/korma/sql/engine.clj#L231) where it eventually maps to `korma.sql.fn/agg-count`:

```
(clojure.core/let [q__2640__auto__ (kc/select* 'foo)]
  (korma.sql.engine/bind-query
    q__2640__auto__
    (clojure.core/let [res__2641__auto__ (korma.core/fields
                                           q__2640__auto__
                                           [(clojure.core/->
                                             q__2640__auto__
                                             (korma.sql.fns/agg-count
                                               :*))
                                            :cnt])]
      (if nil
        (korma.core/group res__2641__auto__ nil)
        res__2641__auto__))))
```

Comment: Thank you sw1nn. That works indeed even though I don't fully understand the behavior of the ~' here. What does (count :*) actually represents? Why doesn't the function count gets executed during the eval phase?

Comment: I added some further clarification of what ``(count :*)`` represents

Comment: Thank you!! Now I understand. I actually had a look at the implementation of aggregate but only now I understand that the (count) function doesn't really get eval'ed but replaced by the macro at compilation time with agg-count!! I should read the code a bit more carefully ;)